# What is the optimal way to find words in a string in any order with regex in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

So I have a string " I have a BIG RED CAR"

I want a user to be able to put in part of the string in any order. So they can write "CAR BIG RED" and the string will be found. I know I can do this by doing multiple IsMatch calls with a Regex string or I could use one string with anchors such as `"^(?=.*CAR)(?=.*RED)(?=.*BIG).*$"`. I was wondering what would be the best option or is there an even better option?

Note: I am using C#, so any .net regex should work.
All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Just a note: I would add `\b` to make sure matched contents are whole words not part of a word: `^(?=.*\bCAR\b)(?=.*\bRED\b)(?=.*\bBIG\b).*$`

Comment: can you explain a little further, re-reading this,  do you mean "I have a BIG SHINY RED CAR" to match with "CAR BIG RED"?  or do you mean only if those 3 words are together in some particular combination?

Comment: I mean "I have a BIG SHINY RED CAR" to match with "CAR BIG RED"?

Comment: damn, would be more interesting if it wasn't :)

Comment: Well Keith, I believe my Regular expression would find the first occurrence of the three words in any order and i'm sure you could add a plus to repeat this to find every occurrence. If you want to share your thoughts on the problem someone would find that helpful. But yeah sorry just wanted to see if the words were there at all.

Comment: You don't need the `.*$` at the end, by the way.

Answer (score 13):

Stepping outside the realm of Regex, you could do something like this:

```
string s = "I have a BIG RED CAR";

var searchTerms = "CAR BIG RED".Split(' ').ToList();
var hasTerms = searchTerms.All(s.Contains);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could just check the words in the String against the words in the search String.

you could use Linq for this if you want

### Linq:

```
List<string> items = new List<string>
{
    "I have a BIG RED CAR",
    "I have a BIG GREEN TRUCK", 
    "I have a BIG YELLOW BOAT"
};

string searchString = "CAR BIG RED";
string result = items.FirstOrDefault(x => searchString.Split(' ').All(s => x.Split(' ').Contains(s)));
```

---

### Regex:

With `RegEx` you could concatenate all the individual words into a pipe delimited string and use with the `\b` operator to check for the whole words.

```
string sentance = "I have a BIG RED CAR";
string searchString = "CAR BIG RED";

string regexPattern = string.Format(@"\b({0})\b", searchString.Replace(" ","|"));
if (Regex.IsMatch(sentance, regexPattern))
{
    // found all search words in string
}
```

However there couild be a nicer way to do this with RegEx, I only know the basics of RegEx

Comment: char[] delimiter1 = new char[] { ' ' };
    string result = items.FirstOrDefault(x => searchString.Split(delimiter1, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).All(s => x.Split(' ').Contains(s)));          //This helps get ignore more than one spaces which would help in my case but otherwise that is a pretty good way to go about it.

Comment: I believe your regex example will match any of the words as you are inserting what I would consider an or with the bar. So although the string would find a match if you added more to the string it would still find a match which is not what I am trying to do. Although I still like your first response.

Answer (score 0):

A simple  idea without LINQ:

```
var st = "CAR BIG RED".Split(' ');
var sm = "I have a BIG RED CAR";
bool res = true;
foreach (string s in st)
    res &= sm.Contains(s);
```

Comment: 1) `s` used twice 2) `&=` starting at `true` instead of `|=` starting at `false`? Because you need ALL to be present right?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Array.FindAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kkxfxdd.aspx) method. See the example in the link.